# Tracking In-App Purchases Changes

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

We are running an application that interacts with In-App Purchases on iOS. All purchases made through the app are cataloged in a database and receipt validation is completed for those purchases when the user loads their account. After searching, I was unable to find a way to monitor changes that the user makes within their iTunes Account.

Let’s say that the user navigates to the iOS Settings App-> iTunes and App Store-> View Account -> Subsriptions -> and changes the subscription in this view. How do we monitor that change?

Can we access an API or framework that returns the current subscription status for a users iTunes account? The answer that I gathered through research was NO.

What’s the recommended method to track these changes?

Answer (score 1):

Subscription and receipt validation comes in picture when we implement Auto Renewable In App Purchase to check that subscription is active or not.

So when you remove/deactivate subscription from iTunes settings for particular product, after completion of that period of auto-renewal(Week/Month/Year), you received receipt that will not renewed after that period, so you can detect that product is no more available to use and you can deactivate or hide that feature for that user. To obtain up-to-date information as you process events, your app should verify the latest receipt with the App Store.

Check [cancellation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH7-SW5) process.

**Status Update Notifications**

You can implement `statusUpdateNotification` to check that.The [statusUpdateNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH7-SW13) is an HTTP POST.

[Enable server notifications for auto-renewable subscriptions](https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/dev0067a330b)

Comment: I understand that a receipt validation will return expired if the subscription has been cancelled. My question specifically said how do we monitor subscription changes. We’re wanting to know how to track If a user upgrades or downgrades a subscription through their ITunes account within the Settings App.

Comment: check this link to implement notification alert for subscription states : https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/dev0067a330b

Comment: Fantastic. That’s exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! Yeah